# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CFBundleCopyResourceURL",

Tags: c++, qt, app-bundle, cfurl-encoding

Trying to access the file path to the resources folder in a Mac .app bundle using Qt. Here's my code:

```
CFURLRef appUrlRef;


appUrlRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("AFE-MP-512"),NULL,NULL);
CFStringRef filePathRef = CFURLCopyPath(appUrlRef);



qDebug() << filePathRef;

// Release references
CFRelease(filePathRef);
CFRelease(appUrlRef);
```

The only thing I have is a pushbutton on the form to run the code. Getting the following error when trying to compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFBundleCopyResourceURL", referenced from:
      MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() in mainwindow.o
  "_CFBundleGetMainBundle", referenced from:
      MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() in mainwindow.o
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() in mainwindow.o
  "_CFURLCopyPath", referenced from:
      MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() in mainwindow.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in mainwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ProgramLaunch.app/Contents/MacOS/ProgramLaunch] Error 1
13:18:21: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project ProgramLaunch (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

I have the following includes in mainwaindow.h

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFURL.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBundle.h>
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link with the CoreFoundation framework. You can add the following to your qmake project:

```
LIBS += "-framework CoreFoundation"
```